# How to jokingly express an "if you pay me, I'll say it" attitude?

Tags: phrase-requests

Let's assume I am an expert in an academic field. I have my opinions, however if I were invited and paid to give a lecture I would be willing to support opposing views.

Question: What would be a possibly ironic (or at least without despise) way to describe such an attitude?

Disambiguation: Something like "if you paid me I would support that" or "the theory for which one pays wins." I am looking for a phrase or proverb describing the attitude, that one might jokingly use to refer to himself.

Comment: The response to that  “Will you do it” question is: “What’s it worth to ya?” or “I’m always for sale... for the right price.”

Comment: *My support and arguments are for sale. What's your offer?* (Sad to see this  from a real academic.)

Comment: "Charming/soothing/enthusiastic/authoritative/trustworthy voice for hire—no questions asked."

Comment: I can't add my own answer, but I'm surprised to see nobody has suggested "selling out," which can work well in a self-deprecating context. "For the right price, I'd gladly sell out!"

Comment: Sophist - since your example involves academia.

Comment: Has no one mentioned the word "lobbyist", as in "I'm a lobbyist at heart"?

Comment: What do you mean by "without despise"? That's not really grammatical in English. Possibly "without spite"? Or something else?

Comment: “Never trust a person whose loyalty can be bought.”

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can consider the proverb ***He who pays the piper calls the tune***.

> The person who provides the money for something has the right to determine how it’s spent. *[[OD]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/he-who-pays-the-piper-calls-the-tune)*

Answer (score 131):

My opinion on that is negotiable.

Comment: +1, this is a great way to express the sort of thing the OP is looking for.

Comment: I liked this answer better before the edit.

Comment: Haha, how ironic :D

Answer (score 46):

> I'm an ethical man. I follow the golden rule. The one with the gold makes the rules.

You wanted something humorous and this certainly fits a [classic pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(writing)). You want something joking, and this is definitely going to be taken in jest. It's also something that gives you a way to back out if the first line gives you an indication that your audience might not be primed for such a joke.

Answer (score 31):

The quote of the comedian Groucho Marx

> Those are my principles, and if you don't like them... well, I have others.

could give the desired result in the appropiate context.

Comment: Pretty sure there's never a bad time to drop a Groucho Marx line :-)

Answer (score 27):

The phrase **open to the highest bidder** is applicable and shows up about 700,000 times when entered into google.

Comment: I also like the 'hired gun' answer, which is another very common phrase.

Comment: This doesn't really sound _joking_ to me—more like something I might say disapprovingly to describe the asker.

Comment: I would have thought it was "**for sale** to the highest bidder" not "open to" him.

Answer (score 15):

The usual in academia is "mercenary". If you happen to be an ethicist, for example, you might jokingly call yourself a "mercenary ethicist".

> Motivated solely by a desire for monetary or material gain.

[mercenary. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved November 3 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mercenary.]

In the case of an ethicist, the joke is clear; for other disciplines, that you are jokingly referring to yourself may be communicated by tone and context.

Comment: I've never heard mercenary used in academia.  I've heard 'hired gun' used to refer to contractors in the private sector, though.

Comment: @publicwireless, of course your experience is comprehensive, yet a search on google--admittedly a very crude instrument--yields only 7 hits for "hired gun academic" and a mere 346 for "mercenary academic" (exact phrases).

Comment: In regard to this usage of "mercenary", I find that it's most common to describe one's motives as mercenary, not the individual themself. e.g. "That was a mercenary decision on his part."

Answer (score 11):

You could say:

> I'd gladly be a ***hired gun*** for the other side.

Or, more lightheartedly:

> I'm a rhetorical ***gun-for-hire***.

Combining this idea with the currently most popular answer gets you:

> My opinion is negotiable because I'm a rhetorical ***gun-for-hire***.

Or...

> As a rhetorical ***gun-for-hire***, my opinion ***is*** negotiable.

(Stress on the word "is" gives the last one some comedic timing, I think.)

Answer (score 6):

A person who does that, especially a plaintiff's [expert witness](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/expert+witness) in medical malpractice trials, is often called a [whore](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whore).

Comment: And the verb is self-prostitution.

Comment: Would you use it jokingly to refer to yourself? Like "you know, I'm a whore so I will do it?"

Comment: I don't see why not.  I think it's sort of tongue-in-cheek to begin with.

Comment: +1 My first thought exactly. Although I'd like to see an adjective to give context. Maybe a "speech-giving whore"?

Comment: This would be taken extremely offensively in many situations. I would take care using this term.

Comment: Please! The term "courtesan" is *so* much more chic! :-)

Answer (score 5):

> I have my opinions, but I also **really** like money.

Answer (score 5):

I used to believe in that, until someone gave me 25,000 reasons to believe otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Australians have a term "cash for comment" meaning you give me cash and I'll comment in your favour (without disclosing the payment).

This Phrase came about after some well known commentators/reporters were caught out making positive comment in support of particular businesses in apparent unbiased editorials.  However they failed to disclose their financial arrangements with those businesses.  Such deals are of course considered unethical in terms of journalistic integrity- But I probably didn't need to say that.

Answer (score 4):

I think ***[corrupt](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/corrupt)*** may fit the context described:

> - lacking in integrity; open to or involving bribery or other dishonest practices: *a corrupt official; corrupt practices in an election.*

(Collins)

Comment: Would you use it jokingly to refer to yourself? Like "you know, I'm corrupt so I will do it?"

Comment: @macraf Maybe not in this form, but something like "I'm not incorruptible" may work.

Answer (score 4):

Whose bread one eats, whose words one speaks...

This is actually a literal translation of a Dutch proverb, but it is used in English too.

I've also seen it appear in English as "Whose bread you eat, his song you sing", but that version feels awkward to me (for the record: I'm Dutch).

Comment: The version with singing is known also in slovak language (Koho chleba jes, toho piesen spievaj). Something related from hungarian: A dog barks, money talks.

Comment: Pretty sure the second version is the more grammatical one, although it's a bit archaic all the same.

Answer (score 2):

"If you got the money honey, I got the time"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.This post would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest this term, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 2):

There’s a property appraiser in my area who is known as “[First name], **true to the task at hand**, [Last name]” in recognition of his/her ability to produce appraisals that always somehow seem to fit the needs of the entity commissioning/paying for the appraisal.

(e.g., tax assessments commissioned by cities/counties [and appraisals commissioned by sellers] always run high; condemnation appraisals commissioned by cities/counties/public utilities/highway-transportation officials [and appraisals commissioned by purchasers] always run low; and depending on the economy and funds available/required, appraisals commissioned by lenders and/or borrowers can go either way)

Although this appraiser and his/her appraisals are clearly inconsistent and subject to change, they "always remain true and faithful to the **[task at hand](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=task+at+hand)**"
 (i.e., “the **current** task that [he/she] is doing[;] that [task that he/she is] **currently** working on.” from Urban Dictionary).

Because of the possible positive connotation of being “true/faithful to the task at hand” (at least when the current task is a noble one), I think that this phrase/notion could be used successfully in your example (where the current task is the pleasing of a paying customer, and therefore perhaps not so noble) to subtly and jokingly express the notion that you’re after, perhaps as follows:

“[Don’t worry,] **I’m** [well-known as/proud to be known as] **someone whose opinions and testimony *always remain true and faithful to the task at hand*.**”

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***customer is always right*** (or ***client is king***) which, used ironically, can mean something along the lines of, if someone is paying for a job, they get to say how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the opposition but **money talks**.

Comment: "money can buy cooperation; having money makes one influential."  That's a different sense than what the OP asks for.

Comment: I have always heard it used in the sense of "Money Talks" ill do whatever it is as long as I get payed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the clearest way to express the intent is "my opinion is for sale", which is a fairly common English idiom. It's generally used in a [negative sense](https://www.google.com/search?q=opinion%20for%20sale&oq=opinion%20for%20sale&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.445j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=%22opinion%20for%20sale%22) when discussing *other's* opinions, but could also be used self-deprecatingly. It does risk coming off negatively, though.

Another possible phrase would be that ["every man has his price"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EveryManHasHisPrice), which states that *everything* is negotiable. It's a little harder to reference the speech-giving and keep the phrasing recognizable, but could be used in context. It also lends itself well to witty follow-ups such as "And mine is pretty affordable", "What's your budget?", etc. This would be seen more jokingly than the first option, and might be spoken by someone with no actual intent of following through.

Answer (score 0):

You could quote [Don Henley](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/donhenley/thegardenofallah.html):

> I can get you any result you like.  What's it worth to ya?

And then hope they get the reference.

Answer (score -1):

If you argue the opposing side, either to extend the conversation or to test for issues with your own view, you can be described as `playing Devil's Advocate`.  You don't necessarily have to be paid to do it-- programmers, architects, designers, etc., do it all the time to determine potential weaknesses.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_advocate

Answer (score -1):

Hold your arms straight out in front of you, hands hanging down loosely; tilt your head slightly to one side; stare vacantly into the distance; intone in your best 'Igor' voice, "Yeth, marthter..."; then lurch away on stiff-kneed legs...

(RIP Terry Pratchett)